# InnerHTML not rendering as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently making an Ajax call which returns an array of different projects in a portfolio.
Once the call is successful, I want to loop through the array and create a bootstrap carousel displaying each project name and details as a carousel item.

The issue that I'm having is that when I try to add HTML-code to the #project-carousel and #project-carousel-indicators, nothing shows up.

```html
<div class="row" id="project-section">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="project-carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators" id="project-carousel-indicators">
        <!-- loop -->
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" id="inner-project-carousel">
        <!-- loop -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getProjects(), false);

function getProjects() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Portfolio/getProjects',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
      var innerCarousel = document.getElementById('inner-project-carousel');
      var carouselIndicators = document.getElementById('project-carousel-indicators');

      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
          //This is being hit but it doesn't render the innerHTML
          carouselIndicators.innerHTML = `<li data-target="#project-carousel" data-slide-to="${i}" class="active"></li>`;
          innerCarousel.innerHTML =
            `<div class="item active">
                <div class="row item-wrapper">
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <h3>${result[i].Client}</h3>
                        <p>${ result[i].Description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
        } else {
          //this is also being hit but it doesn't render the innerHTML
          carouselIndicators.innerHTML = `<li data-target="#project-carousel" data-slide-to="${i}"></li>`;
          innerCarousel.innerHTML =
            `<div class="item">
                <div class="row item-wrapper">
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <h3>${result[i].Client}</h3>
                        <p>${ result[i].Description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
        }
      }
    },
    error: function(event, jqxhr, settings, excpetion) {
      showError(event, jqxhr, settings, excpetion);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You keep overwriting the `.innerHTML` of both elements, so I would assume the code only shows the last project. You also have `type: 'POST'`, are you sure that's what the backend expects? Anyway, to append, you should use `$(carouselIndicators).append("html here");`

Comment: Also, remove `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice and is not necessary in your code anyway

Comment: In fact, you are overwriting the `.innerHTML` instead appending items one by one. Then, [each item should be wrapped](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-controls) by a `carousel-item`, the item you want to show should be delivered with `active` class. Then, your carousel controls will control the item to active by hitting **previous** or **next**

Comment: Nice, will give this a try!

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG, this did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

Call carousel manually after you append the html content.

```
$('.inner-project-carousel').carousel();
```